# Como fazer um update sempre adicionando+1 no mysql

Tags: mysql

Olá,

Como faço um update em uma coluna do mysql inserindo sempre +1 a cada update novo?
E como tirar -1 da mesma coluna ?

Eu tentei isso:

```
"UPDATE tb_comment SET good=+1 WHERE id=:idComment"
```

Só que inseriu apenas 1, não continuou a contagem 1..2..3..4 de acordo com os update que eu dava..

E para tirar 1 registro tentei isso:

```
UPDATE tb_comment SET good=-1 WHERE id=:idComment
```

E falhei miseralvemente

Answer (score 2):

Resolvido!!

Era só fazer o seguinte:

```
"UPDATE tb_comment SET good=good+1 WHERE id=:idComment"
```